# ¿Cómo eliminar dos registros de tablas diferentes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Cómo eliminar dos registros de dos tablas? Lo he intentado con un winner join y solo me elimina el registro de una sola tabla:

```html
DELETE w
FROM FACTURA_ARTICULO w
INNER JOIN FACTURA_SERIE e
ON w.FACTURA=e.FACTURA
Where e.FACTURA='100'
```

si coloco la variable **e** después de la **w** que está frente a **delete** me marca error.

> uso sql server 2008

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Esto (SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query) te puede ayudar

Comment: Hola Ivan, podrias indicar si existe relación entre las tablas ?

Comment: no existe relación, solo las uno a través de w.FACTURA=e.FACTURA

Comment: En una de las tablas la columna Factura es clave foránea de la otra tabla, si no no tendría sentido la Unión que mencionas. Podrás indicar el modelo de datos de tu base de datos?

Comment: Deberías etiquetar el motor de base de datos que estás usando. La syntaxis para `DELETE` varía entre ellos

Comment: Por buenas practicas nunca se deben eliminar registros solo cambiar de estado

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server no permite borrar datos de dos tablas en un solo `DELETE`. De todas formas, la única condición de unión del `JOIN` es sobre la columna `FACTURA`, y luego tienes una condición en el `WHERE` que lo limita a `FACTURA = 100`. Por lo tanto bastaría con hacer un `DELETE` por cada tabla:

```
DELETE FROM FACTURA_ARTICULO
WHERE FACTURA = '100';

DELETE FROM FACTURA_SERIE
WHERE FACTURA='100';
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que si tienes un foreign key y lo tienes on delete cascade, podrías borrar el valor de la tabla principal y borraria los valores relacionados con ese foreign key de las tablas asociadas al mismo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Después del `DELETE` debes de poner las tablas que serán afectadas por la instrucción `DELETE`:

```
DELETE w, e
FROM FACTURA_ARTICULO w
INNER JOIN FACTURA_SERIE e
WHERE
    e.FACTURA='100'
    w.FACTURA=e.FACTURA
```

Comment: me marca error en la coma, lo intente asi como me indicas pero no funciona

Comment: La funcionalidad del inner join no es la adecuada.

Comment: Corregí la respuesta @Ivxn